# C++ segmentation fault on allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation

Well, before this I searched a lot about "what caused segmentation fault", but I did not find anything about my situation.

Here is thing:

```
DNA_INIT Creation::InitalizeUserActivity()
{
  SUData *curr = new SUData[__USERCOUNT];
  readSQL(curr,__USERCOUNT);
  // return something
}
```

I have this function in dna.h and, this is its file which is named dna.cpp

```
SUData *readSQL(SUData *tmp,int size)
{
  ifstream getSQL;
  getSQL.open("../noSQL/StoredUserDataNoSQL.inc");

  int count;
  string tmpstr;

  ifstream focus;
  focus.open("../instruction.bin",ios::app);
  focus >> tmpstr >> count;
  focus.close();

  int c = 0;
  tmp = new SUData[size];

  while(getSQL >> tmp[c].id >> tmp[c].access >> tmp[c].u_name >> 
    tmp[c].u_surname >> tmp[c].u_username >> tmp[c].u_password 
    >> tmp[c].u_email )
    {
      c++;
    }

  return tmp;
}
```

When I tried to execute that it gives me Segmentation Fault. I tried things but still same. Thanks for advice.

**Edit : I removed  tmp = new SUData[size]; but it is still same**

Comment: How big is `__USERCOUNT`? Are you sure it;s enough? Your question says "on allocation" - which line is causing the problem?

Comment: Why are you opening an *input* stream in *append* mode? Also, going by its name (`../instruction.bin`) it's a binary file, so maybe you should open it in binary mode?

Comment: As for your problem, whenever a program of yours crashes, then you should run a debug build of it in a debugger. The debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and also let you examine and walk up the function call stack and also let you examine values of variables. Please run your program in a debugger, and tell us *where* it crashes.

Comment: And one thing to think about, what if there are more data in the `../noSQL/StoredUserDataNoSQL.inc` file than the variable `size` indicates? Then you will write outside of the allocated memory for `tmp`, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should probably have e.g. `while (c < size && getSQL >> ...)`

Comment: @doctorlove its just 4

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it crashes on "readSQL(curr,__USERCOUNT);"

Comment: @SashaValentine On which line of `readSQL()` it crashes? Did you ever use debugger?

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with gdb you can also just print some information, for a small program like this.

Comment: I would like to see the definition of `SUData`. Are the fields you are trying to read into long enough, and properly initialized?

Comment: @PeterScheider i kinda did that already this source is huge i and use return values for where program crashes and i reduced to loop of while.Nothing wrong with SUData i'm sure coz im using it somewhere else too.

Comment: Then it's most likely just running out of bounds because c >= size.

Comment: if(c > size) break; is it helpful ?

Comment: `while (c<size && (getSQL >> tmp[c].id >> ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, now I see the problem: You allocate a pointer in `InitalizeUserActivity`, pass it to `readSQL` which *allocates again* (causing a memory leak).

The bigger problem is that, as all arguments, the pointer is passed *by value*, i.e. the `readSQL` function is only operating on a *copy* of the pointer from `InitalizeUserActivity`. When the pointer is changed inside the `readSQL` function, only the copy is changed. This of course leads you to read data into memory that can't be accessed from outside the `readSQL` function.

There is a very simple way to solve this, and that is to not allocate anything new inside the `readSQL` function (as it's already allocated).

Comment: clear explanation, so how can fix this , I mean i want to change curr in readSQL function how can do that.

Comment: @SashaValentine Just don't allocate again inside the `readSQL` function. Then there's no memory leak (provided you free the memory allocated in `InitalizeUserActivity`), and the data is read into the memory allocated in the `InitalizeUserActivity` function.

Comment: @Sasha Either you do not pass allocated data to the function and allocate inside and return the memory allocated in the function; or you follow Joachim's suggestion: you pass allocated memory into the function, do not re-allocate inside (and, I might add, do not return anything -- why? tmp's value was set outside the function and is not changed).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you allocate a space for `curr` and send it to the function `readSql` and again allocate another space for the `tmp` variable; `tmp` hold allocated address in `curr`, its wrong you don't need to reallocate.

Comment: when i remove tmp = new SUData[size]; it doesn't change still same situation

Comment: it doesn't matter, its wrong implementation, you cant debug your code?

Comment: I would not expect the program to cash *there* because of the repeated allocation. (It may crash later, of course, when it tries to use presumed information read into the caller's `current`.)

Comment: why you think c not exceeds your size?

Comment: the variable c, you sure the line numbers in your file isn't bigger than __USERCOUNT

Comment: just add a printf in your loop and check one by one tmp[c] properties